# Problem to shape my input date to the keras model

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, attention-model

Here is the model definition:

```
from tensorflow.keras import Model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Bidirectional
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.datasets import imdb
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Embedding, Dense, LSTM
from tensorflow.keras.losses import BinaryCrossentropy
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences
from keras_self_attention import ScaledDotProductAttention, SeqSelfAttention
from tensorflow.keras import Model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Bidirectional

# Model configuration
additional_metrics = ['accuracy', 'mse']
batch_size = 64
loss_function = BinaryCrossentropy()
number_of_epochs = 10
optimizer = Adam()
validation_split = 0.20
verbosity_mode = 1 

# Define the Keras model
in_data = Input(shape=(None, 768), batch_size=batch_size, name='input_sentences')  # every input is a list of sentences
lstm = Bidirectional(LSTM(50, return_sequences=True), name='bi-lstm')(in_data)
att = SeqSelfAttention(attention_activation='sigmoid', name='seqselfatt')(lstm)
att_lstm = LSTM(10, return_sequences=False, name='bi-lstm-att')(att)
output = Dense(5, activation='sigmoid', name='output')(att_lstm)  # 5 outputs 5 -> 1

model = Model(inputs=[in_data], outputs=[output])

# Compile the model
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss=loss_function, metrics=additional_metrics)

# Give a summary
model.summary()
```

> Model: "model"
> _________________________________________________________________ Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #
> ================================================================= input_sentences (InputLayer) [(64, None, 768)]         0
> _________________________________________________________________ bi-lstm (Bidirectional)      (64, None, 100)           327600
> _________________________________________________________________ seqselfatt (SeqSelfAttention (64, None, 100)           6465
> _________________________________________________________________ bi-lstm-att (LSTM)           (64, 10)                  4440
> _________________________________________________________________ output (Dense)               (64, 5)                   55
> ================================================================= Total params: 338,560 Trainable params: 338,560 Non-trainable params:
> 0
>
> ---

Here is the shape of my data: x_train and x_test are lists of arrays

```
x_train[0].shape, x_test[0].shape, len(x_train)
# ((2, 768), (3, 768), 100)
```

when running fit, got this error:

```
history = model.fit(x_train, 
                    y_train, 
                    batch_size=batch_size, 
                    epochs=number_of_epochs, 
                    verbose=verbosity_mode, 
                    # validation_data=(x_test, y_test)) 
                    validation_split=validation_split)
```

> Epoch 1/10
> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call
> last)  in ()
> 6                     verbose=verbosity_mode,
> 7                     # validation_data=(x_test, y_test)
> ----> 8                     validation_split=validation_split)
>
> 9 frames
> /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py
> in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks,
> validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight,
> sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps,
> validation_batch_size, validation_freq, max_queue_size, workers,
> use_multiprocessing)    1098                 _r=1):    1099
> callbacks.on_train_batch_begin(step)
> -> 1100               tmp_logs = self.train_function(iterator)    1101               if data_handler.should_sync:    1102
> context.async_wait()
>
> /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py
> in **call**(self, *args, **kwds)
> 826     tracing_count = self.experimental_get_tracing_count()
> 827     with trace.Trace(self._name) as tm:
> --> 828       result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
> 829       compiler = "xla" if self._experimental_compile else "nonXla"
> 830       new_tracing_count = self.experimental_get_tracing_count()
>
> /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py
> in _call(self, *args, **kwds)
> 860       # In this case we have not created variables on the first call. So we can
> 861       # run the first trace but we should fail if variables are created.
> --> 862       results = self._stateful_fn(*args, **kwds)
> 863       if self._created_variables:
> 864         raise ValueError("Creating variables on a non-first call to a function"
>
> /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py
> in **call**(self, *args, **kwargs)    2939     with self._lock:
> 2940       (graph_function,
> -> 2941        filtered_flat_args) = self._maybe_define_function(args, kwargs)    2942     return graph_function._call_flat(    2943
> filtered_flat_args, captured_inputs=graph_function.captured_inputs)  #
> pylint: disable=protected-access
>
> /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py
> in _maybe_define_function(self, args, kwargs)    3356
> call_context_key in self._function_cache.missed):    3357
> return self._define_function_with_shape_relaxation(
> -> 3358                 args, kwargs, flat_args, filtered_flat_args, cache_key_context)    3359     3360
> self._function_cache.missed.add(call_context_key)
>
> /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py
> in _define_function_with_shape_relaxation(self, args, kwargs,
> flat_args, filtered_flat_args, cache_key_context)    3278     3279
> graph_function = self._create_graph_function(
> -> 3280         args, kwargs, override_flat_arg_shapes=relaxed_arg_shapes)    3281
> self._function_cache.arg_relaxed[rank_only_cache_key] = graph_function
> 3282
>
> /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py
> in _create_graph_function(self, args, kwargs,
> override_flat_arg_shapes)    3204             arg_names=arg_names,
> 3205             override_flat_arg_shapes=override_flat_arg_shapes,
> -> 3206             capture_by_value=self._capture_by_value),    3207         self._function_attributes,    3208
> function_spec=self.function_spec,
>
> /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py
> in func_graph_from_py_func(name, python_func, args, kwargs, signature,
> func_graph, autograph, autograph_options, add_control_dependencies,
> arg_names, op_return_value, collections, capture_by_value,
> override_flat_arg_shapes)
> 988         _, original_func = tf_decorator.unwrap(python_func)
> 989
> --> 990       func_outputs = python_func(*func_args, **func_kwargs)
> 991
> 992       # invariant: `func_outputs` contains only Tensors, CompositeTensors,
>
> /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py
> in wrapped_fn(*args, **kwds)
> 632             xla_context.Exit()
> 633         else:
> --> 634           out = weak_wrapped_fn().**wrapped**(*args, **kwds)
> 635         return out
> 636
>
> /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py
> in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
> 975           except Exception as e:  # pylint:disable=broad-except
> 976             if hasattr(e, "ag_error_metadata"):
> --> 977               raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
> 978             else:
> 979               raise
>
> ValueError: in user code:
>
> ```
> /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:805
> ```
>
> train_function  *
> return step_function(self, iterator)
> /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:795
> step_function  **
> outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
> /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:1259
> run
> return self._extended.call_for_each_replica(fn, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
> /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:2730
> call_for_each_replica
> return self._call_for_each_replica(fn, args, kwargs)
> /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:3417
> _call_for_each_replica
> return fn(*args, **kwargs)
> /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:788
> run_step  **
> outputs = model.train_step(data)
> /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:754
> train_step
> y_pred = self(x, training=True)
> /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py:998
> **call**
> input_spec.assert_input_compatibility(self.input_spec, inputs, self.name)
> /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/input_spec.py:207
> assert_input_compatibility
> ' input tensors. Inputs received: ' + str(inputs))
>
> ```
> ValueError: Layer model_1 expects 1 input(s), but it received 100 input tensors. Inputs received: [<tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:0'
> ```
>
> shape=(None, 768) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:1'
> shape=(None, 768) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:2'
> shape=(None, 768) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:3'
> shape=(None, 768) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:4'
> shape=(None, 768) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:5'
> shape=(None, 768) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:6'
> shape=(None, 768) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:7'
> shape=(None, 768) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:8'
> shape=(None, 768) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:9'
> shape=(None, 768) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:10'
> shape=(None, 768) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:11'
> shape=(None, 768) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:12'
> shape=(None, 768) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:13'
> shape=(None, 768) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:14'
> shape=(None, 768) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:15'
> shape=(None, 768) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:16'
> shape=(None, 768) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:17'
> shape=(None, 768) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:18'
> shape=(None, 768) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:19'
> shape=(None, 768) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:20'
> shape=(None, 768) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'Iterat...

Comment: what is `in_data.shape` and  `outputs.shape`

Comment: Can you add minimum, complete code to reproduce this issue.

Comment: I've added the required information (missing imports). the `in_data.shape` is (None, 768) (per one input sample)

Comment: @AniketBote , the x_train x_test are both lists of ndarrays of shapes (None, 768) and y_test and y_train are lists of n ints.

Comment: @Kenan I've just made some modifications, and the code error changed too.